# The term 'node' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

PS D:\javascripr\wen_shen_test_package> node hellow.js
node : The term 'node' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was inclu
ded, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1

- node hellow.js
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (node:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
  ```

Excuse me ，what can i change for?

Comment: have you installed nodejs? If yes, was that particular powershell terminal already open before you started the installation? If yes, close it and open a new powershell so that it will pick up the changed `PATH` environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

You have not installed node.js on your pc.
https://nodejs.org/en/download/

If it is already installed

1.Create index.js file on your desktop and add this code in it:

```
a=2
b=3
console.log(a*b)
```

2. shift+ right click on your desktop, click on open powershell window here.
3. enter command:
   node index.js

it will show the value of a*b

Above given code is an example of how to access particular js file using node

Comment: sorry,but i have check to powershell ，there have version

Comment: nnnnnn,my code is use console.log(hellow node ); but unfortunately is show this ,

Comment: put hello node message inside " ", like this console.log("hello node")

Comment: yes i try to succeed ，i delete the node 64 and i  download again 32  ,is work .