# nodejs is not recognized even though just installed

Tags: node.js

I just redownloaded node because I was having issues with the following error:

```
& : The term 'C:\Program Files\nodejs/node_modules/node/bin/node' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify 
that the path is correct and try again.
At C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.ps1:14 char:5
+   & "$basedir/node_modules/node/bin/node"   $args
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Program File...s/node/bin/node:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I redownloaded then ran the cmd:

```
node -v
```

and got the above error.

I have no idea what this means as I definitely just installed it.

Comment: I can see mixed path separators, for starters.

Comment: Yeah my research is telling me its something to do with my path env variable

Comment: A similar question is this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68599835/the-term-node-is-not-recognized-as-the-name-of-a-cmdlet?rq=2 but no clear answer there either. I'd reinstall, to be honest.

Comment: I have reinstalled, same issue

Comment: Solved the issue, uninstall node, reinstalled 32bit version

Comment: > maybe add this as an answer and accept it, even if it's your own question, so others can quickly navigate to the solution :)

Answer (score -1):

Unsure why this fixes the problem but if you run across it:

```
1. uninstall node (including the nodejs folder in Program Files)
2. reinstall node (32bit)
3. restart
```

If someone knows why this fixes it, lmk